# How do I split this string in python 2.7 keeping spaces?

Tags: python, regex, string, list, python-2.7

I am looking for a way to take a string and output it as a list with each character split?

```
>>> sentence = 'hello I am cool'
>>> what_i_want(sentence)
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'I', ' ', 'a', 'm', ' ', 'c', 'o', 'o', 'l']
```

However, this doesn't seem to work:

```
>>> sentence = 'hello I am cool'
>>> sentence = ' '.join(sentence).split()
>>> print sentence
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'I', 'a', 'm', 'c', 'o', 'o', 'l']
```

It doesn't print the space in between! Also, this doesn't work:

```
>>> import re
>>> splitter = re.compile(r'(\s+|\S+)')
>>> sentence = 'hello I am cool'
>>> splitter.findall(sentence)
['hello', ' ', 'I', ' ', 'am', ' ', 'cool']
>>> sentence = ' '.join(sentence)
>>> splitter.findall(sentence)
['h', ' ', 'e', ' ', 'l', ' ', 'l', ' ', 'o', '   ', 'i', '   ', 'a', ' ', 'm', '   ', 'a', ' ', 'j']
```

Can anyone tell me an efficient and relatively easy way to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Passing a string to [`list`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list), you will get a list of single-character strings.

```
>>> sentence = 'hello I am cool'
>>> list(sentence)
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'I', ' ', 'a', 'm', ' ', 'c', 'o', 'o', 'l']
```

Comment: No need to use regular expression. But here's a solution using regular expression: `re.findall('.', sentence)`

Comment: Thank you to everyone who responded! +1

Answer (score 6):

Using `list()`:

```
>>> list(sentence)
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'I', ' ', 'a', 'm', ' ', 'c', 'o', 'o', 'l']
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone who responded! +1

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `for` loops on strings, if you want to iterate each character.

```
for chr in 'hello I am cool':
    print(chr)
```

It should result in:

```
h
e
l
l
o

I

a
m

c
o
o
l
```